# Irrelevant text insertion into website header

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have noticed that innapropriate text has been added onto my header. I have gone through all necessary php files but I am unable to find where this text has been inserted. It might be a javascript but I am completely clueless on how to proceed finding it.

This is the section on file (header.php):

```
<div class="logo">
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php tfuse_logo();  ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"  alt="Medica" border="0" />
                        </a>
                    </div><!--/ .logo -->
```

As you can see the  tag of the inserted unwanted text is not visible in the logo div. But, the logo displays it nevertheless and if I inspect element on Chrome it shows up there too.

Others seem that others have this issue too, but I couldn't get any wiser from how they solved it (not the identical problem).

Can someone please help me and have a look at the website: [www.claremontclinic.net](http://www.claremontclinic.net)

**The innapropriate text in the header is "manie porn".**

Comment: Why do you have two alt? What does  <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> contain?

Comment: From a comment elsewhere: 
run grep -r porn /path/to/your/wordpress/root/folder to see if it is in the code, or do a db dump with mysqldump and then search there for the word porn, to see if it is in the database

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-hacked-link-added-under-logo

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for now, Add this javascript code in footer:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("a").each(function(){
      var ele =jQuery(this);
       if(ele.text()=='manie porn'){
        ele.hide();
       }
     });
  });
</script>
```

This will hide the inappropriate text and will buy you some time to find the ambiguous code.